# Exporting data driven pages with wms in arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, wms, data-driven-pages

I use Arcmap 10.2.2.

I have a problem with export my map with data driven pages when I use a wms as a background layer. It seems that it can't render or download the background for the pages, only the one I am currently seeing. All other pages becomes white. Is there some way I can force arcmap to cache/download the wms for the other pages?

Comment: can you add the wms background as a basemap layer? (I believe they're not automatically set as basemap layer)

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but I still get white pages.

Comment: What WMS are you using?  Can you provide its service URL so we can test?  What format are you exporting to?